# Java DNS suffix

Tags: java, list, dns

When I do ipconfig /all I see DNS Suffix Search List. I need to retrieve that value from java.
Does anyone knows how to get it or where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

The DNS suffix list is read from

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\SearchList
```

Comment: For that to be useful, you'll also need to combine that with an answer from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java

Comment: In my computer the DNS list is in this location: 
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient\SearchList
It seems that this path may change a little bit depending on the windows version. Is there a way to read the values from java network configuration, so that I don't depend on the Windows version?
I am using dnsjava library, maybe there is a way to do it with this library. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Runtime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class to execute Windows commands (e.g. `ipconfig /all`) and parse the standard input.